# Multiple custom field values in strong soap for Netsuite

Tags: javascript, soap, netsuite

Long shot, I'm using strong SOAP to retrieve saved search results from Netsuite.

If my search contains just 2 columns, sales rep and revenue then it works fine.

The revenue column in the search is from a custom field.

If I add another custom field then everything is undefined.

I have tried so many combinations, but I cannot fathom the syntax for the below for me to pass values from multiple custom columns to variables in the script.

the 'const fieldId' variable does show me the fields internal id in the logs, but again as soon as I add another column to the search this also becomes undefined.

I know it will have something to do with identifying the searchValue by the scriptId of the field, but can't make it all connect.

```
let searchRows = result.searchResult.searchRowList.searchRow;
                  searchRows.forEach((row) => {
                     const searchValue = row.basic.entityId.searchValue;
                     const fieldId = row.basic.customFieldList.customField.$attributes.scriptId;
                     const customField = row.basic.customFieldList.customField.searchValue;
                     console.log(searchValue);
                     console.log(fieldId);
                     console.log(customField);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so when you have multiple custom fields in the custom field list it stores them in an array, so you have to extract based on position in array like this:

```
const fieldId = row.basic.customFieldList.customField[0].searchValue;
const customField = row.basic.customFieldList.customField[1].searchValue;
```